# What http status code should I use when customer configuration is not correct?

Tags: web-services, rest, http-status

I am unsure what http status code to return when a customer calls my API, but the requested action cannot be completed ***for reasons that the customer can fix***.

In this case, the http request itself may be fine, but it will not succeed until the customer logs into the front end and updates their configuration. (I will return a body with some informative message to indicate this.)

Is 412 - Precondition Failed - appropriate for this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **412 Precondition Failed**
>
> The *server* does not meet one of the preconditions that the requester put on the request.

This statuscode has a spefic meaning. It is about a condition that the *client* stated in the request, whichthe *server* was unable to fullfill. **Don't use this status code for your scenario**.

The only HTTP status code that can be used is `400 Bad Request`. It is the catch-all status code for all errors that the *client* can fix. Since you return detailed information about how the client can do this, the client has everything necessary.

see Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicion that 412 was not right for this case.